# Is possible to configure OpenLDAP Crypt passwords without using a salt?

Tags: ldap, openldap, salt, sha512, sha2

From the docs I got this config that works but use a salt,

password-hash {CRYPT}
password-crypt-salt-format "$6$%.16s"

and I need to store passwords in the LDAP directory that have been generated without salt encryption.

Comment: You need to be insecure why?

Comment: because I need to store a lot of password in the insecure format in the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had better to use another password storage scheme that does not do salting like {SHA} or {MD5} instead of {CRYPT} :

```
password-hash {SHA}
```

---

If using {CRYPT} is a requirement :

- You can still provide a *static* salt (! bad, unsecure, nearly as if no salt !), just comply with the given format:

  ```
  password-crypt-salt-format "$6$%.16s"
  ```

  `$6$` is the crypt identifier for the `SHA512` schema, and we provide a 16-chars long salt :

  ```
  ~$ mkpasswd -m sha-512 --salt 'verybadseasoning' secret1
  $6$verybadseasoning$Q2kceqwB2uYT2tU./QF.qRCIWjMQdObEAZ71Ni5Ko1zJOnxUwpu3oMeyjtgiR3hSVHIT20Ay9V1.pXaNhkHYk/

  ~$ mkpasswd -m sha-512 --salt 'verybadseasoning' secret2
  $6$verybadseasoning$SHof1u2BCPJhYoVOk.LkWax7n5g28rzMkNCRAC5NmlT29GSeWLAlv2AoSkOS4rYfMUXsmTcyIxKDUU8aL7TlP0
  ```

  Note that `mkpasswd` won't allow using an empty salt :

  ```
  ~$ mkpasswd -m sha-512 --salt '' secret
  Wrong salt length: 0 bytes when 8 <= n <= 16 expected.
  ```
- Or you can try to make crypt *ignore* the given/generated salt string whatever it is (by taking zero character from it) :

  ```
  password-crypt-salt-format "$6$%.0s"
  ```

  It tells crypt() to use a SHA512 algorithm, the `%s` being substituted with a string of zero characters of salt (`%.0s`). I can't tell if slapd makes the %s conversion mandatory or not, but setting just `"$6$"` without any substitution for salting may do the trick as it *means* the same (no salt), i.e :

  ```
  ~$ php -r 'print(crypt("secret", "$6$"));'
  $6$$2M9DchxW4txWyTYoZrH9D3VvAAQxBpEezYsLY6Cao.jwzEXpyL9xwip9hiUZX7GqTqe/E/z6iKvZqXUuqniQH.
  ```

See [slapd.conf(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/slapd.conf)

**Note that a lack of salt exposes your system to dictionary attacks.**

Comment: In this format "$6$%.0s" it would ignore the token too, and I want to ignore just the salt, sorry if I'm missing something, and thanks for your answer

Comment: No this is a way to specify `$6$` alone (no salt). `password-crypt-salt-format` expects a string in [sprintf(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) format. `$6$%.0s` actually tells crypt() to use SHA512 (`$6$`), with a substituted string of 0 characters (`%.0s`) from any passed-in or generated salt. See the php implementation example, the output shows an empty salt ($$) followed by the encrypted hash as expected. I updated the answer and hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply import user entries with existing *userPassword* values without salt. The password verification will work provided the hash scheme is one supported by your local OpenLDAP installation.

The config directives *password-hash* and *password-crypt-salt-format* when setting new passwords.